# PySpark - select distinct rows based on max value from another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing my first spark job and I'm stuck in a situation that I don't know how to solve with Spark. I have a list like this one:

```
mylist = [
  {"id":1,"name":"sally", "role": "manager", "updated_at": "2020-01-13T18:42:21Z"},
  {"id":1,"name":"sally", "role": "director", "updated_at": "2020-01-14T10:17:45Z"},
  {"id":2,"name":"eric", "role": "leader", "updated_at": "2020-01-28T07:33:58Z"},
  {"id":3,"name":"john", "role": "leader", "updated_at": "2020-01-01T20:00:00Z"},
  {"id":2,"name":"eric", "role": "developer", "updated_at": "2020-01-10T08:28:31Z"},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in mylist).show(truncate=False)

df.show(n=10)
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to filter this dataframe and get distinct rows (unique ids) based on max `updated_at`. The max value of `updated_at` represents the last status of each employee.

The expected output from example above is:

```
  {"id":1,"name":"sally", "role": "director", "updated_at": "2020-01-14T10:17:45Z"},
  {"id":2,"name":"eric", "role": "leader", "updated_at": "2020-01-28T07:33:58Z"},
  {"id":3,"name":"john", "role": "leader", "updated_at": "2020-01-01T20:00:00Z"},
```

If is it possible? For what function should I look?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `row_number()-window` function and get only the `latest record` for the uniqueids.
Then create a `json output` for the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

mylist = [
  {"id":1,"name":"sally", "role": "manager", "updated_at": "2020-01-13T18:42:21Z"},
  {"id":1,"name":"sally", "role": "director", "updated_at": "2020-01-14T10:17:45Z"},
  {"id":2,"name":"eric", "role": "leader", "updated_at": "2020-01-28T07:33:58Z"},
  {"id":3,"name":"john", "role": "leader", "updated_at": "2020-01-01T20:00:00Z"},
  {"id":2,"name":"eric", "role": "developer", "updated_at": "2020-01-10T08:28:31Z"},
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in mylist)

w =  Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("updated_at"))

df1=df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w)).filter(col("rn") == 1).drop("rn")

df1.toJSON().collect()

#result
#[u'{"id":1,"name":"sally","role":"director","updated_at":"2020-01-14T10:17:45Z"}', 
#u'{"id":2,"name":"eric","role":"leader","updated_at":"2020-01-28T07:33:58Z"}', 
#u'{"id":3,"name":"john","role":"leader","updated_at":"2020-01-01T20:00:00Z"}']

#write to HDFS..etc filesystems
#only use repartition with less data or else use coalesce(1)

df1.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save("<path>")
```