# Getting the distinct Max from a range of timestamps using Spark Sql or Pyspark (Duplicate)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in the following format:

[image]

here is the dataset in a more friendly way:

| index | score | date | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | A |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | A |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | A |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | A |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | A |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | A |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | A |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | A |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | A |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | A |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | A |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | A |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | A |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | B |
| 707 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:15 | B |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | B |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | B |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | B |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | C |
| 707 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:15 | C |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | C |
| 707 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:15 | C |
| 707 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:15 | C |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | C |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | C |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | C |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | C |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | C |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | C |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | C |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | C |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | C |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | C |
| 708 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 15:41 | C |
| 709 | 0.7 | 10/31/22 13:42 | C |
| 706 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 14:45 | C |
| 705 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:02 | C |
| 707 | 0.5 | 10/31/22 15:15 | C |

from it I need to get highest value based on timestamp in this case it will be the very first one.
I'm using spark SQL to create the query, which is already conditioned to get me the max index, the max score and the date is condition based on the first and last day of the range. Giving me the max date. However, I need to have the max distinct (I know this can be done in regular SQL, but spark/Pyspark doesn't seem to have an equivalent function that can be used within the SQL query).

the query is as follows:

```
spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT max(index) AS index, \
                  max(score) AS score, col2, col3,\
                  col4,\
                  max(make_timestamp(last_day(col5))) AS date\
                  FROM table \
                  GROUP BY index,  score,\
                  col3, col4, date").registerTempTable("table1")
```

if I were to use purely SQL, I could use MAXDistinct(), but this function is not supported, what would be the equivalent for it? so I could just the very first row?

[image]

And discarding the rest as they all are repeats of the same row but with those 3 columns different due to the timestamp.

Comment: too vague your dataset.

Comment: it has more than 20 columns, but these are the columns I care to get only the very first row showing up in the screenshot

Comment: You need to add more rows that show effect of max etc

Comment: Also, please provide the datasets in a copy-paste-able format, so it is easier for people who will try to help

Comment: I added a small dataset for it, with one more column to distinguish.

Comment: All same values

Comment: No, they are not, but the rows like they are the same except for the 3 main columns I'm displaying in the sample dataset. The only thing that changes is the timestamp and with ot the index and score. So, I only need to get the latest (final) timestamp for a one specific date if I use select distinct the resulting dataset above is what I get along with other conditions . Each row is distinctive due to the timestamp more which is driving the rest.

Comment: This has been the closest to what I've been looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232900/pyspark-select-distinct-rows-based-on-max-value-from-another-column

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this correctly, but according to your print, you want the oldest timestamp line using Pyspark. So this code should work

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.table("default.csv_stack_csv")  # your table
df = df.withColumn("date_parsed", F.to_timestamp(F.col("date"), "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"))
df = df.sort(F.col("date_parsed")).drop("date_parsed").limit(1)
df.show()

+-----+-----+--------------+
|index|score|          date|
+-----+-----+--------------+
|  709|  0.7|10/31/22 13:42|
+-----+-----+--------------+
```

Comment: Did tou notice the last column on the dataset table. There 3 different records: A, B, and C they all have multiple timestamps I will need to get the latest for each record. I'll check your response to see if it works on my use case

Comment: I tried your solution above, and at least for my use case, it does not resolve the issue. it drops all rows of the dataframe.- Thank you though.